# Issue while upgrading from JDK 11 to JDK 17 with oracle driver ojdbc8

Tags: java

I am currently working on upgrading from JDK 11 to JDK 17. However, I encountered an issue with the Oracle driver, specifically the ojdbc8 driver we are using. After researching, I learned that ojdbc8 only supports JDK 8 and JDK 11, while the ojdbc11 driver is designed for JDK 11, JDK 17, and onwards. Additionally, the ojdbc11 driver is compatible only with Oracle Database versions 21 and 23, whereas we are currently using Oracle 19c.

I am seeking information on whether there is any workaround or solution to continue using the ojdbc8 Oracle driver with JDK 17?

Thanks in advance.

Any workaround or solution if available?

Comment: ojdbc11 is compatible with Oracle 19c https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your situation, where you are upgrading from JDK 11 to JDK 17 and using Oracle 19c with the ojdbc8 driver, here are some considerations and potential solutions:

[Official Compatibility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-782A399A-78F5-4D1A-A4F3-F5AE35DE62DA):  it's important to note that the ojdbc8 driver is officially compatible with JDK 8 and JDK 11, but not with JDK 17. Additionally, the ojdbc11 driver supports JDK 11, JDK 17, and onwards, but is only compatible with Oracle Database versions 21 and 23, not with Oracle 19c.

Potential Workarounds and Solutions:

Testing ojdbc8 with JDK 17: Although it's not officially supported, you might consider testing the ojdbc8 driver with JDK 17 in a non-production environment to assess its functionality. In some cases, drivers can work with newer JDK versions than they are officially compatible with, but this approach comes with risks of instability and lack of official support.
Using ojdbc10 Driver: According to the article from [Loïc Lefèvre](https://medium.com/db-one/oracle-jdbc-drivers-a84e2b5f7eb9), the ojdbc10 driver is compatible with both JDK 11 and JDK 17. It might be worth exploring if this driver version works with Oracle 19c, as it could be a middle ground that supports both your database and the newer JDK version.